# tableau version 10.1.1 regexp_match unknown

Tags: regex, tableau-api

I am currently have a calculated fields using regexp_match to check the pattern matching. However, when i am putting the tableau file on the client laptop tableau with 10.1.1, it is shown as 'unknown function regexp_match is called'.

I would like to ask is this a version issue? if so, what could be the alternative way to do the pattern matching check on tableau?

Many thanks

Comment: Don't think the regex function have changed in the new version. Could be a data source issue? https://community.tableau.com/thread/227193

Comment: I see lampbob, thank you for the information.  It could be a data source issue as im connecting to the MS SQL server. I have tried in version 10.1.4 it seems working fine. but the client laptop doesnt have that version. Do you know if it is possible to do the pattern matching without using the regular expression function?

Comment: You could try use the CONTAINS() function?

Comment: I have both Tab 9 and Tab 10. I can see function REGEXP_MATCH in Tableau 9 but not in version 10. It seems either it is being removed or there is a glitch.